# Parentheses size

Tags: fontsize, punctuation

How can I change parenthesis size in whole document?

I have bunch of 'coc(o)nunt' or 'co(c)onut' words.

Standard parenthesis seems too big, footnotesize looks ok.

Replacing any `(` with `{\footnotesize(}`, looks rather poorly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you using parentheses only in that context?

Comment: Yes. Is simple \renewcommand solution will be enough?

Comment: @Erasm Are you sure they are too big? Try `coc(go\"t)nunt`. These type of decisions are best left to the font designers. What font are you using?

Comment: @Erasm No, a `\renewcommand` will not be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend to apply such an adjustment on a global scale.

The method I would prefer would be to define a proper command for these reduced parentheses

```
\usepackage{relsize}
\def\<#1\>{%
  \raisebox{.12ex}{\smaller[2](}#1\raisebox{.12ex}{\smaller[2])}}
```

and use it as

```
coc\<o\>nut
```

so that you'll have the chance to use normal parentheses.

Comment: Fixed typo: '\def\<#1\>{%
  \raisebox{.12ex}{\smaller[2](}#1\raisebox{.12ex}{\smaller[2])}}'

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended, but here is a solution, using the `scalefnt` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalefnt,graphics}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\newcommand\Sb[2][0.95]{%
  \bgroup
    \def\PL{{\scalefont{#1}(}}%
    \def\PR{{\scalefont{#1})}}%
     \PL#2\PR
  \egroup
}
\scalebox{7}{coc\Sb[0.9]{got}nunt}
\scalebox{7}{coc\Sb[0.9]{go\"t}nunt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from the images, when the text has ascenders or descenders the brackets will look wrong. I have used the `scalebox` from the graphics package to scale the full word up so it can be see better. Generally I would recommend that one leaves these type of decisions to the font designer or switch fonts.